# Using SLD to style according table column value

Tags: geoserver, sld

How to style various points with different image according to value(text) in the column of table(layer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoServer has some examples of how to style using SLD called [SLD cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/).

In your case you want to combine the [Attribute-based point](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#attribute-based-point) example and the [Point as graphic](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#point-as-graphic) example.

Comment: The links are dead...

Comment: Now the links are updated.